# Prevent user update multiple rows in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to restrict some users to update multiple rows by accident in mysql database? i think it can be done using TRIGGER BEFORE UPDATE but i can not get user query. Also there is no COMPOUND TRIGGER like in Oracle db. Any ideas?

Comment: How someone can "update multiple rows by accident" in mysql database ? Don't you have some admin page to do it ? And if user can do some update, restrict what they can do ?

Comment: I granted update permission for some mysql users (they are juniors) to only one table, so i want them not to update multiple rows accidentally

Comment: Ok but my question is : how do they update the table ? Do they have an interface or they can do request directly in database ?

Comment: If user has permission to update multiple rows how would you identify deliberate multi-row updates and accidental multi-row updates? Or are you saying a group of users may only do single row updates?

Comment: @Michael they update in sql yog, directly in db

Comment: @P.Salmon in this case multi-row = accidental

Comment: I all you have is mysql then no you cannot prevent multi-row updates.

Answer (score 1):

There is my dirty solution using dynamic programming, you can restrict any table/query update

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `foo`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `fooTrigger`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `fooTrigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `fooTable` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN

            SET @inf = '';
            SET @CurrUsr = '';
            SELECT USER() INTO @CurrUsr;
            /*GET CURRENT USER QUERY IN THIS CASE; THERE ALSO MAY BE ANY OTHER USER OR ANY 'like' CONDITION*/
            SELECT INFO INTO @inf FROM information_schema.`PROCESSLIST`
            WHERE USER = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@CurrUsr,'@',1) AND STATE = 'executing' -- and INFO like '%update%'
            ;

            /*MAKE SELECT QUERY USING UPDATE QUERY*/
            SET @inf = REPLACE(@inf, 'UPDATE', 'select count(*) into @nCnt from ');

            SET @beforeSet = '';
            SET @beforeSet = LEFT(@inf,LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@inf, 'SET', 1))); 
            SET @afterWhere = '';
            SET @afterWhere = CONCAT('WHERE ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(@inf, 'WHERE', -1));
            SET @queryNew = CONCAT(@beforeSet, @afterWhere);
            -- SELECT @queryNew;
            /*EXECUTE SELECT QUERY*/
            PREPARE stm FROM @queryNew;
            EXECUTE stm;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;
            if @nCnt > 1 then
                SET @msg = 'TriggerError: \n YOUR ERROR TEXT';
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = @msg;
            end if;

        END IF;
    END;
 $$

DELIMITER ;
```